# Getting substring without messing up UTF-8 string

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8

I have a UTF-8 encoded string that comes from an ajax response, I want to get substring of that string up to the first comma. For the string `"Привет, мир"` it would be `"Привет"`.

Will this work and not run into "multibyte-ness" issues?

```
var i = text.indexOf(',');
if (i != -1) text = text.substr(0, i);
```

Or is it better to use `split`?

Comment: Your code is 100% correct. This is one of the features of both UTF-16 and UTF-8: even though index of a string is a code unit and not a code point, indexOf and alike search will never match a comma (or other <127 ascii char) that is not a comma character. More information on http://utf8everywhere.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript treats strings by *characters*, not by bytes.
As such, yes, that's fine from an encoding/string handling standpoint.
You may treat strings in Javascript as not having any particular encoding, but as a *string of characters*.

```
> "漢字".substr(1)
  "字"
```

---

Note that the above is only a simplification though. As pointed out in the comments, Javascript treats strings as 16-bit code points. This enables you to treat strings "by character" for the majority of common characters, but for characters which are encoded with more than 2 bytes in UTF-16 or characters composed of more than one code point, this abstraction breaks down.

Comment: @R.Martinho But that is in no way exposed through the API, it is an irrelevant implementation detail.

Comment: @R.Martinho Touché. Characters it doesn't support it indeed doesn't support.

Comment: There is no such thing as a character. If you mean unicode codepoint, then the statement is false. For more information, see, for example, http://utf8everywhere.org

Comment: @Pavel OK, fair enough; that was too simplified an explanation. I've edited my answer, but I'd be happy if you could edit it further to remove any incorrectness.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 uses only values higher than 128 to encode characters other than ASCII so an ASCII comma is never part of a multibyte sequence.

Comment: That's actually irrelevant here.

Comment: @deceze, actually it is relevant. Internally JavaScript uses UCS-2 or UTF-16 encoding so it is possible to load UTF-8 as ASCII if the content type doesn't have correct charset. In that case you can split a string in the middle of multibyte sequence but an ASCII comma would never be part of such a sequence so no harm will be done. See that the string in this case comes from AJAX response, not from a string literal.

Comment: It's irrelevant. If the string has been imported into the runtime using the correct encoding, it doesn't strictly have an encoding anymore; you can only access it via the Javascript String API, which deals with characters. If the encoding of the original byte stream was misinterpreted and the String object in the runtime contains garbage characters, all bets are off anyway.

Comment: @deceze, I still think that it is relevant, even if not as relevant as your answer (for which I gave you +1). The point is that in normal cases with correct encoding I agree 100% with you. Additionally, **even if** the UTF-8 encoding was misinterpreted as ASCII or Latin1 or any other 8-bit encoding then splitting on comma would not brake it because of how UTF-8 works with values outside of the 7-bit ASCII range (and it is true for all languages, not only JavaScript). In other words, I agree that your answer is better but I argue that mine is still relevant. :)

Comment: I certainly see your point, but this only applies if UTF-8 was misinterpreted as an ASCII compatible encoding. If your data was mislabeled as, say, Shift-JIS, there's no telling how exactly it would mess up. That's why I'm saying if your string was mishandled, all bets are off anyway. Thanks though. :)

Comment: @deceze Javascript API does NOT deal with characters. It deals with units of one, very specific and not so good encoding, and s[i] can be less than a "character" in your meaning of the word.

Comment: @rsp pic on your profile is not visible; PS: glad you are promoting Gittip